# How to take a screenshot from youtube player

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube-api

I have YouTubePlayerView layout in my xml

```xml
                                <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
                                    android:id="@+id/youtubePlayer"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    app:enableAutomaticInitialization="false"
                                    tools:ignore="TooDeepLayout"
                                    tools:visibility="gone" />
```

which plays videos from YouTube. I need to somehow implement the ability to take a screenshot for the player.

I tried similar ways with bitmaps

```
private fun captureScreenshot() {
    binding.youtubePlayer.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
    val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.drawingCache)
    binding.youtubePlayer.isDrawingCacheEnabled = false
    viewModel.saveScreenshot(bitmap)
}


private fun captureScreenshot() {
    val picture = Picture()
    val canvas =
        picture.beginRecording(binding.youtubePlayer.width, binding.youtubePlayer.height)
    binding.youtubePlayer.draw(canvas)
    picture.endRecording()

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        picture.width,
        picture.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    )

    val bitmapCanvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    bitmapCanvas.drawPicture(picture)
    viewModel.saveScreenshot(bitmap)

}
```

but in these methods, instead of the correct image, I get just a black screen, please tell me if it is possible to correctly take screenshots for YouTubePlayerView in android.